# How to create a python GUI that displays a grid and allows the user to select and fill individual cells?

Tags: python, user-interface, mesa-abm

**A bit of background:**

I'm learning about Agent-Based Modeling, and just implemented Conway's Game of Life using the Mesa package. I've read about initial configurations for this model that produce interesting phenomena, and want to recreate them (i.e. Gosper glider gun, The R-pentomino, etc.)

I thought an interesting learning project would be to create a GUI application that displays a grid, and allows the user to select the cells they want to instantiate the model with.

**Problem:**

I wish to display a GUI containing a grid like the following:
[image: Grid]

And then the user can click the cells they want to populate, and it will display like the following: [image: Grid w/ Selections]

Then, when the user clicks a 'Save State' button (or presses a specified end key), their selections are saved to a numpy array for instantiating the model.

I'm not sure where to even begin. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried any UI/GUI framework?

Comment: @AdrianKrupa I am reading about PyQt5 currently. I'm thinking that using its Table widget might suffice, even if it lacks the style I wrote about above. I really would like to approach it in a way similar to what I described in the original post, though.